# How detect brute force attack to a website on XAMPP?

Tags: xampp, brute-force

I have `DVWA` on `XAMPP` server on my Windows 8 and i used a software to implement brute force attack on DVWA.Now my question is how can i detect this brute force attack log on XAMPP? Or generally other attacks(e.g. sqli, xss)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to find patterns in your Apache access logs (Apache is a part of XAMPP). During a typical "brute force" attack the access logs will find multiple POST requests to a specific log-in page. Have a look at you access log while/after your running a brute force attack.

Typically the access logs wil include multiple login attempts from the same IP address. More advanced, distributed brute forces will connect using various IP's.

A way of preventing these attacks is by limiting the amount of possible logins to e.g. 10 attempts each minute. A way dealing with detected "brute forcing" IP addresses is (automatically) blocking them by using either a firewall of access control system (like .htaccess files).